# Query Importrange Where 2 condition in 1 column

Tags: google-sheets

I've been successful filtering all data where Col 2 = 440, but I want to include in the filter the same column but the value should be 293.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1qEZduDQkolARr1chAlZftP4LZ5VUh4KpuIkf_NRZ_ba", "Cons_Data!A2:H"), "Where Col2=440")
```

Basically, it must show all data where Column 2 = 440 and 293

Comment: `Where Col2=440 or Col2=293`?

Comment: You can't use `Col`  to query a range e.g."`A2:H`" without using `{}` curly brackets see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937234/19529694)

Comment: @Osm I maybe wrong, but `IMPORTRANGE` removes all range references, so you could use `Col` without `{}`

Comment: @TheMaster yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1qEZduDQkolARr1chAlZftP4LZ5VUh4KpuIkf_NRZ_ba", "Cons_Data!A2:H")}, 
 "where Col2=440 
     or Col2=293", )
```